# Xamarin.IOS and Xamarin.Android programmatically detect build or apk version change to trigger splash screen on login

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a xamarin.android and xamarin.ios app and I want to display a splash screen if the apk build or version number is new. In other words, if I update my apk from version 5 to 6, I want to be able to detect that change after login and trigger the splash screen. I see some version and build controls in xamarin.essentials, but am unable to determine the proper implementation of this. Can someone help me get on the right track and help me solve this issue? I did not provide code because it is not needed but I may provide it if needed.

Comment: A "SplashScreen" runs before/while the application loads, which means you won't have access to anything. If you're wanting to show a screen after the user logs into the app, that's different.

Comment: Hi, yes I need to load a screen after authentication is completed. So, a splash screen activity cannot be changed after login? Do I have to create a custom activity?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make custom activity. I would make a simple non-animated splash screen that loads quickly, then an activity whose only code is to check version, then launch desired animation. (Almost nothing in it, so it also loads quickly.) While animation playing, load whatever is needed for main activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need seems pretty simple:

```
if(Xamarin.Essentials.VersionTracking.IsFirstLaunchForCurrentVersion)
    // trigger that splash screen
```

To make this work, Xamarin.Essentials need to be initialised first, as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/version-tracking)